# ¿Como puedo limipar la pantalla del Terminal de MySQL en Windows 10?

Tags: mysql

Resulta que he intentado muchas maneras para limpiar la pantalla de MySQL entre ello esta los siguientes :

`clear`

`cls`

`System(cls);`

`system clear`

`\! clear`

`\! cls`

Pero ninguno de ellos me funciona

También lo intente esto : Haga clic derecho en el marco superior de la consola -> Propiedades -> Diseño -> y la Pantalla de ajuste de Tamaño de Búfer de Altura a gran número. Pero tampoco nada.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Hola, intenta con el siguiente comando `mysql> \! cls`

Comment: Lo voy a mirrar

Comment: tampoco funsiona

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL está usando?, comandos como: `mysql> system cls` o `mysql> \! cls` está soportado en Windows desde MySQL 8.0.19.

Comment: el profesor me dijo que instalase la de MySQL 8.0.0 @wchiquito

Comment: Entiendo que si instaló MySQL 8.0.0 podrá instalar MySQL 8.0.19 ó 8.0.23 (la versión más reciente a día de hoy).

Comment: le preguntare @wchiquito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partir de la **versión 8.0.19 de MySQL** puedes hacer un `system cls` en Windows o `system clear` en Ubuntu

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo pero ya lo he solucionado :)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> para generar una nueva linea, luego escribe

```
system cls
```

y confirmas.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> limpia la terminal cuando usas MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución.

1 - Ir a panel de control > Programas > activar o desactivar una característica de Windows y habilitar subsistema linux y reiniciar cuando se haya agregado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 - Una vez reiniciado ir a la tienda de Microsoft store y buscar Ubuntu e instalar y iniciar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3 - Una vez iniciado pulsar enter e escribir el usuario

4 - Abrir el terminal de windows 10 y escribir bash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5 - una vez dentro eso instalamos mysql con lo siguiente `sudo apt install mysql-server`

6 - Escribir para ejecutar mysql :  `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

7 - Escribir `system clear` y ya se borra la pantalla

Comment: Vale, pero está ejecutando y accediendo a MySQL a través de otro sistema operativo (en este caso Ubuntu), consola e interprete (shell). En ese caso funcionarán todos los comandos aplicados a sistemas operativos *nix, por ejemplo: `Ctrl + L` también limpairá la pantalla.

Comment: Tiene pinta de una solución overkill. Un gran procedimiento sólo para tener una consola que haga algo en particular...